# Which protocol specifies the meaning of each bit in a CAN message?

Tags: can

A lot of books and articles describe the basic idea of CAN (controller area network) and the requirements to the physical layer as well as the data link layer.
But I didn't find any description how the bits of the payload gets assigned to some specific information like a wheel speed.
Is there a special protocol? Is there a basic database that describes the assignments of every bit to an information?

example:
ECU1 sends the following payload to ECU2: 1111 0000 1111 0000
How does ECU2 know which bit describes what information?

Comment: By definition such as the first 4 define the code then the second a reading and the third a code for error etc

Comment: which means there is a database that collects all the "defintions", right? Is there a special name for that? There should be a protocol on the application layer shouldn't it?

Comment: Do a google search, one of the first 3 links: https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/page/simple-intro-to-can-bus/language/en

Answer (score 0):

This is specified by the application layer - refer to the "OSI model" where CAN itself only specifies hardware and data link layers. All nodes on the bus need to be aware of the application layer protocol used.

Common application layer standards are CANopen, J1939 and DeviceNet. In automotive systems, it is most common to use custom, OEM-specific protocols for control signals, though car OBD protocols specifically are somewhat well standardized (OBD2 etc).